# Why is No data message showing? (trying to create google charts)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I am new to the Google Charts API. I was following some examples to create a chart with a search function, involving MySQL on XAMPP, but it only returns "options part" and "no data" messages.

I tested the SQL query, and it works.

My code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$query1  = "SELECT partido, COUNT(*) as num_faltas FROM reuniao WHERE presenca LIKE '%Injustific%' GROUP BY partido";
$query2  = "SELECT DISTINCT partido FROM reuniao";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    echo "['" . $row['partido'] . "'," . $row['num_faltas'] . "],";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Graficos </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Partido', 'Faltas injustificadas'],
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                    echo "['" . $row['partido'] . "'," . $row['num_faltas'] . "],";
                }
                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {'title': 'Numero de Faltas injustificadas por Partido'};
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 900px;">
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the complete data you are fetching (an array or JSON)

Comment: well the while in the code return this: 
[' CDS-PP ',5],[' PCP ',1],[' PS ',3],[' PSD ',3],

Comment: Do you want to know the rest of the data in the table "reuniao"?

Comment: If i paste [' CDS-PP ',5],[' PCP ',1],[' PS ',3],[' PSD ',3] (the wihle output), instead of the while loop it works, so why ?

Comment: not sure if it will make a difference but arrayToDataTable is a static method  'new' keyword is not needed...

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code and it's working:

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Partido', 'Faltas injustificadas'],
            <?php
            $query1  = "SELECT partido, COUNT(*) as num_faltas FROM reuniao 
            WHERE presenca LIKE '%Injustific%' GROUP BY partido";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                echo "['" . $row['partido'] . "'," . $row['num_faltas'] . "],";
            }
            ?>
        ]);
```